# Как использовать сортировку orderBy в sqflite во Flutter?

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3, flutter, dart, android-sqlite

Как отсортировать список по возрастанию / убыванию в базе данных sqflite?

В интернете все примеры ограничиваются следующим кодом:

```
result = await db.query(tableName,
        columns: columns,
        where: 'columnName LIKE ?',
        whereArgs: ["%$query%"]
    );
```

Но нигде нет примеров использования в этой конструкции "orderBy: ".

Как правильно сделать сортировку по возрастанию / убыванию?

Comment: В Flutter из коробки sqflite нет. О чем вообще вопрос и как на него можно дать ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить Вам два варианта:

1. если посмотрите сигнатуру метода query, то можете обратить внимание что у него есть необязательный параметр orderBy, через который можно передать по какому столбцу сортировать, типа:

   ```dart
   result = await db.query(tableName,
           columns: columns,
           orderBy: 'sum ASC'
           where: 'columnName LIKE ?',
           whereArgs: ["%$query%"]
       );
   ```
2. для запросов можно не использовать обёртки, а написать в строку сам запрос и передать его методу rawQuery, что-то типа:

   ```dart
   final sql = 'SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE id = ? ORDER BY $column DESC';
   await rawQuery(sql, [id]);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Можно это легко сделать с уже полученной коллекцией:

```
result.sort((a, b) => a.someProperty.compareTo(b.someProperty));
```